# Drawing faces over a country without overlapping borders in Three.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, three.js, drawing

My problem is that when creating faces for a country, there are faces which overlap the border.

Below is the image when all coordinates are used when creating the faces

[image with all values (coordinates)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqAit.png)

---

values_axis1 contains all the X coordinates [63.0613691022453, 65.1611029239906, 66.0721609548093, 68.8109022381195, 71.1822098033678..]

values_axis2 contains all the Y coordinates [34.37065245791981, 35.30003249470688, 38.11207931425505, 38.228254752215044..]

values_axis3 contains all the Z coordinates

---

```
for (var i = 0; i < values_axis1.length; i ++) {
   object_geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(values_axis1[i], values_axis2[i], values_axis3[i]));
   object_geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, i + 1, i));
}
```

Buy changing **i++** to **i+=2** we get this [image of skipping some values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5iLr.png)

Arrow obviously shows the point zero where all triangles are drawn from.
Below is the part of code for that.

```
object_geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(DRAW_FROM_HERE, i + 1, i));
```

This isn't per say a programming problem but more like a 'is there a algorithm for this'.

I could check for faces that collide with a border from **point zero** and skip them but then there would be holes and that would need to be filled by drawing from some other location. That could be done manually but doing that for all the countries in the world would take ages. I'm sure this could be done by somehow calculating where the holes are but I have no idea how that would be done.

If someone comes up even with a really bad solution performance wise it would be great! I'm planning on putting all the results in a file which could then be loaded and drawn since there is really no need to do this processing every time since the borders never move.

---

EDIT: ShapeGeometry was suggested and has been tested. I was wrong when I said that Z coordinates are not relevant but obviously they are due to the curvature of the globe.

Image of the shapeGeometry. [2d but otherwise perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQsFd.png).

Question edited.

**Edit: Solution**

Thanks to @Gilles-Philippe Paillé for suggesting ear clipping. Found a great library https://github.com/mapbox/earcut

Here is updated code for others who might have the same issue.

```
function createVertexForEachPoint(object_geometry, values_axis1, values_axis2,
      values_axis3) {

        var values_x_y = []; // add x and y values to the same list [x,y,x,y,x,y..]
        for (var i = 0; i < values_axis1.length; i++) {
          values_x_y.push(values_axis1[i], values_axis2[i]);
        }

        // https://github.com/mapbox/earcut
        var triangles = earcut(values_x_y);
        // triangles = [37, 36, 35, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 30, …] [a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c..]
        // triangles contain only the verticies that are needed
        // previously all possible faces were added which resulted in overlapping borders

        // add all points, in this case coordinates. Same as before
        for (var i = 0; i < values_axis1.length; i++) {
          object_geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(values_axis1[i], values_axis2[i], values_axis3[i]));
        }

        // go through the list and pick the corners (a,b,c) of the triangles and add them to faces
        for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i += 3) {
          var point_1 = triangles[i];
          var point_2 = triangles[i+1];
          var point_3 = triangles[i+2];
          object_geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(point_1, point_2, point_3));
        }
    }
```

I use a geoJSON which has 'polygon' and 'multipolygon' shapes. This code works for polygons atm but shouldn't need too much tweaking to work with multipolygons since the library supports also holes `earcut(vertices[, holes, dimensions = 2])`.

[image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn90l.png)

Comment: Have you looked at https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry? I don't know if that suits this problem. You could also add a vertex in the center to be 'the point zero where all triangles are drawn from', and then generate triangles from that point to the first and second values in the arrays?! :D (add all all the points and divide them by the amount of points, to get the average of all the vertices). Also, interesting app :)

Comment: As @EthanHermsey suggested, use ShapeGeometry. It supports triangulation of any shape because it internally uses the Ear Clipping Method. Creating a vertex at some point in the center would indeed work for start-shaped polygons, but won't work for general polygon. Moreover, finding a point that "sees" all vertices without intersecting the border is not trivial either, unless you know some properties of the shape in advance.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé That's a good addition. I didn't even think about intersecting, Thanks

Comment: @EthanHermsey and Gilles-Philippe Paillé. Cheers for your advices!
I tried using the shapeGeometry and immediately realised that Z coordinates are quite important.
See the edit in the original post for the result.
Im really happy with the result otherwise. I'm now looking into Ear Clipping if that would be the answer.

Comment: @Kajander A way to still use ShapeGeometry to triangulate polygons embedded in 3D would be to transform polygon vertices so that their Z is all 0, perform the triangulation, the transform back result using the inverse transform. It is a bit cumbersome to perform, but still easier that implementing ear-clipping yourself.

Comment: Or maybe use it in combination with https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry?